# Ansible Is there any way to make global task for use in all playbooks

Tags: ansible

is there any way to create central function only once and call it from every task playbook needing it?
for example, i have this task :

```
- name: Download
  get_url:
    url_username: foo
    url_password: foo
    dest: "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/"
    url: "{{ download_url }}"
```

the same task is copy/paste multiple times in different playbooks 
this is very not efficient.

any way define it once and call it from other playbooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options.

1) Put the task into a file and use [include_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html#include-tasks-dynamically-include-a-task-list) or [import_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_tasks_module.html#import-tasks-import-a-task-list).

2) Create a role with the file and use include_role [tasks_from](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#parameter-tasks_from).

<sup>FWIW. See my libraries of tasks [ansible_lib](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/ansible_lib) and [linux_lib](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/linux_lib).</sup>

---

Q: *"What is the difference between all of them?"*

A: Imported code is present from the beginning of the playbook's execution. Included code will be loaded when the work-flow reaches the point. This influences

- inheritance of the tags
- availability of some variables (e.g. role defaults, ...)

See details

- [Including and Importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html)
- [Creating Reusable Playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#creating-reusable-playbooks)
- [What's the difference between include_tasks and import_tasks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/875247/whats-the-difference-between-include-tasks-and-import-tasks)

---

<sup>([opinion based](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions))</sup>

Q: "What is usually used?"

A: `include_role` is the most powerful and flexible option. See the [parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#parameters) of the module.

---

Q: *"What about import_playbook?"*

A: It's not a module. It's a simple directive to include code. Use `import_playbook` to simplify (modularize) complex playbooks and to change [playbook's parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) on-the-fly (e.g. `hosts, become, ...`) while keeping the [playbook's variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables).

Comment: thanks what is the difference between all of them as from high level they do the same ?
what is usually used ?

Comment: what about import_playbook? is it recommended?

Comment: i trying to implement your suggestions 
can you please see this new question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631744/ansible-include-role-syntax-problem-although-flow-the-documentions