# ansible include_role syntax problem although flow the documentions

Tags: ansible

I try to include_rule but i keep getting errors on the wrong syntax 
this is my file structure :

```
├── roles  
│   └── utilities
│       ├── defaults
│       ├── files
│       ├── handlers
│       ├── meta
│       ├── tasks
│       │   └── d_pack.yml
│       ├── templates
│       └── vars
└── test4.yml
```

the rule d_pack.yml

```
---
- name: Download package
  get_url:
    url_username:
    url_password:
    dest:
    url:
    owner:
    group:
```

the test4.yml

```
---
- name: check if exsist
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:


        - debug:
            msg: "#################################### INCLUDE START ######################################"


        - include_role:
            static:no
            name:utilities
            tasks_from:d_pack
          vars:
            url_username: "{{ user }}"
            url_password: "{{ pass }}"
            dest: "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/"
            url: "{{ myurl }}"
            owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
            group: "{{ ansible_user }}"

        - debug:
            msg: "#################################### INCLUDE END ######################################"
```

i think i follow the examples shown here :
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html
and here :
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html

but still, I'm getting an error:

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
ERROR! 'name' is a required field for include_role.

The error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/ansible/test4.yml': line 13, column 11, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


        - include_role:
          ^ here
```

also after following the yml rules i fixed it to :

```
---
- name: check if exsist
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
     - name: this is test
       include_role:
         static: no
         name: utilities
         tasks_from: d_pack
       vars:
         url_username: "{{ user }}"
         url_password: "{{ pass }}"
         dest: "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/"
         url: "{{ package_url }}"
         owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
         group: "{{ ansible_user }}"
```

I'm still getting this error:
ERROR! Invalid options for include_role: static

```
The error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/ansible/test4.yml': line 6, column 8, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
     - name: this is test
       ^ here
```

**Update** 
now that i removed the static: no 
i have new error as i can see that the role evaluate the dummy parameters first and not the one i inject via the include_role

```
- name: Download package
  get_url:
    url_username: temp
    url_password: tmp
    dest: tmp
    url: tmp
    owner: tmp
    group: tmp

<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588762539.1880841-18280-15848856136034/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
  File "/********/ansible_get_url_payload_xex4nmel/ansible_get_url_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 1494, in fetch_url
    unix_socket=unix_socket, ca_path=ca_path)
  File "/********/ansible_get_url_payload_xex4nmel/ansible_get_url_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 1390, in open_url
    unredirected_headers=unredirected_headers)
  File "/********/ansible_get_url_payload_xex4nmel/ansible_get_url_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 1264, in open
    request = RequestWithMethod(url, method, data)
  File "/********/ansible_get_url_payload_xex4nmel/ansible_get_url_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 643, in __init__
    urllib_request.Request.__init__(self, url, data, headers, origin_req_host, unverifiable)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 354, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  invocation:
    module_args:
      attributes: null
      backup: null
      checksum: ''
      client_cert: null
      client_key: null
      content: null
      delimiter: null
      dest: VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER
      directory_mode: null
      follow: false
      force: false
      force_basic_auth: false
      group: VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER
      headers: null
      http_agent: ansible-httpget
      mode: null
      owner: VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER
      regexp: null
      remote_src: null
      selevel: null
      serole: null
      setype: null
      seuser: null
      sha256sum: ''
      src: null
      timeout: 10
      tmp_dest: null
      unsafe_writes: null
      url: VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER
      url_password: VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER
      url_username: temp
      use_proxy: true
      validate_certs: true
  msg: 'unknown url type: ''********'''
  status: -1
  url: VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER
[localhost] TASK: utilities : Download package (debug)> p task.args
{'_ansible_check_mode': False,
 '_ansible_debug': False,
 '_ansible_diff': False,
 '_ansible_keep_remote_files': False,
 '_ansible_module_name': 'get_url',
 '_ansible_no_log': False,
 '_ansible_module_name': 'get_url',
 '_ansible_no_log': False,
 '_ansible_remote_tmp': '~/.ansible/tmp',
 '_ansible_selinux_special_fs': ['fuse',
                                 'nfs',
                                 'vboxsf',
                                 'ramfs',
                                 '9p',
                                 'vfat'],
 '_ansible_shell_executable': '/bin/sh',
 '_ansible_socket': None,
 '_ansible_string_conversion_action': 'warn',
 '_ansible_syslog_facility': 'LOG_USER',
 '_ansible_tmpdir': '/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588762539.1880841-18280-15848856136034/',
 '_ansible_verbosity': 3,
 '_ansible_version': '2.9.7',
 'dest': 'tmp',
 'group': 'tmp',
 'owner': 'tmp',
 'url': 'tmp',
 'url_password': 'tmp',
 'url_username': 'temp'}
```

Comment: Remove `static: no` or remove indentation. `static` should be on task level. However, if you actually need static behavior then use `import_role` instead.

Comment: hey i removed it , but now i have new problem as the role evaluate the dummy values 
and not the one i set into it via the include_role

Comment: `url` should be in correct format. Please check https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html#parameter-url

Comment: i found the problem , in the role the values should be the name of the variables I'm passing from the include_role section :
 url_username: "{{ user }}"  not  url_username: tmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try below two methods, please notice the **blank space** between name and 
the role name utilities, and also I am using ansible 2.9.1, there is no static option for include_role.

if you have further questions, please let me know.

```
---
- name: run role utilities
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
      - include_role:
          name: utilities
          tasks_from: d_pack
```

I highly recommend you follow below patten when write ansible playbook, this is recommend by ansible official doc. Each task have a task name. please refer https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#always-name-tasks

```
---
- name: run role utilities
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: run the role
      include_role:
        name: utilities
        tasks_from: d_pack
```

Comment: Thanks i updated my question with your suggestion but still I'm getting error

Comment: @user63898, remove the static: no

Comment: i remove it , but now  in the vars: not setting my role with the parameters